# MaxDiff scaling - Survey Questionnaire

Tags: r

MaxDiff scaling is a very popular method for understanding customer preferences. I was wondering if we can create a survey questionnaire for MaxDiff analysis in R. Can anyone shed some light on this.

Comment: Can you please expand your question? SO is best suited for precise  programming questions on the matter.

Comment: Please have a look at the guide lines in the help center for [**what and how to ask on SO**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: http://www.r-bloggers.com/why-doesnt-r-have-a-maxdiff-package/